# How to find the connection information to Sybase DB

Tags: linux, sybase

I have Sybase installed on my Linux box (to which I have "root" access). However I do not have the access details to Sybase, is there any way I can find the port Sybase is listening on, and also use linux root user to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You should check sybase interface file at the first.
Read f.e. this article about interface file structure.

http://www.outlands.demon.co.uk/sybase/index.html

After that copy env. variables from sybase user bash profile ant try to connect to database with isql utility (also explained in this article).